# How do I classify text using cosine similarity?

Tags: nlp, vectorization, text-classification, cosine-similarity

I have got a typical sentiment analysis task, my dataset consists of text and 3 classes (negative, neutral, positive). I have vectorized text using Bert sentence transformers and calculated the cosine similarity metric of my test_embeddings: [output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PUqx.png). Now, how do I classify each test sentence and calculate accuracy?

Comment: Please ask non-programming questions on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/. I don't think calculating cosine similarity between training and test instances is the right method for this task, unless you're trying to do some kind of manual k-NN method?

Comment: Thank you! I actually solved the problem, using this guide: https://www.sbert.net/docs/usage/semantic_textual_similarity.html Found the cosine similarity pairs of test/train datasets, found the highest pair of each test input, built a simple classifier and got the accuracy. Turns out, using cosine similarity for text classification task for morphologically complex languages is a fairly efficient method :)

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved the problem, using this guide: sbert.net/docs/usage/semantic_textual_similarity.html

Found the cosine similarity pairs of test/train datasets, found the highest pair of each test input, built a simple classifier (that matches the highest values and the classes in the cosine pairs), and got the accuracy.

Comment: Be sure to include the relevant elements of the link you included, otherwise your answer will be deleted as a "link-only answer". Remember that link you provided might disappear.